# How does Angular know that bindings should be re-applied to refresh UI elements with updated data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I think I understand how controller functions initially fill a scope with a bindable object graph, and how angular directives associate elements of that graph with aspects of the UI.

I also understand how the initial data can be copied into the UI fields the first time, when the document loads in the browser.

What I'm unclear about is how Angular knows to refresh the bound UI elements when the underlying data changes.

I can see two possible methods:

1) At load time, when all the setup runs, Angular wraps the bound JS objects in a more elaborate structure which allows the objects to basically "raise events" to the Angular binding mechanism when assignment statements make them "dirty."

2) (And this is my best guess) When user JS code does something like a AJAX callback that it knows will update the data, it also explicitly calls a method on the module or the controller to force a re-bind.

Are either of these guesses close?

Answer (score 1):

Angular does "dirty-checking" on `$watch`-ed variables.

Here's [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) about scope variables and how they integrate with Angular's digest loop

Read [this article](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/) for deeper understanding.

Comment: I need something a little more explicit than a re-direct to an article. For instance, is $watch always used, or can you explicitly invoke a re-bind of the entire object graph.

Comment: Thanks for the link, though, it is helpful.

Comment: In my opinion you got your answer, but I'll update my answer with a link to Angular's own documentation about the very question you're asking. StackOverflow is about providing answers to specific and concise questions. It's not about a "readers digest" version for people who don't feel like reading documentation.

Comment: To answer your question in the comment, yes, you can invoke a rebind: `$scope.$apply()`. This is typically needed when the scope variable is updated via an async callback (such as with `setTimeout`).

Comment: So in the typical case, what prompts Angular to do an automatic rebind to the scope (an automatic re-application of the directives)? Is it hooking event handlers to the user interface pieces that are bound, so that UI changes (like a textbox entry) forces a rebind? Or is it doing some sort of rebind with a timer or loop (polling)?

Comment: It integrates with the browser's event loop, and when that executes it checks for any values that have changed. Honestly, read the documentation - here's an even more direct [link to the right section](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope/#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop) within the URL I already provided.